# Java option MaxDirectMemorySize reported differently by java vs. jinfo

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, jinfo

I restarted a Java process with new memory options `-Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=6G` and wanted to verify if these changes got correctly applied, especially the 6G of direct memory.

The first solution I found for verifying this was via `java` itself, but this simply reported a `0`, implying that my new settings had no effect:

```
bash-4.4$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxDirect
    uintx MaxDirectMemorySize                = 0                          {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

A second solution I found later was via `jinfo`, which apparently confirm the `6G` that I indended to set:

```
bash-4.4$ jinfo -flag MaxDirectMemorySize 1
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=6442450944
```

I've relied on the `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` for other purposes before, but now I wonder why it doesn't return the expected values. Why are `java` and `jinfo` returning different results?

Comment: `java {nothing} -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` creates a new JVM, changes none of its configuration from the default, and prints the resulting configuration, which is the default configuration with no changes. `jinfo {option} pid` attaches to an _existing already running_ JVM and obtains information from or makes changes to the configuration of _that_ JVM, although it's very unusual for pid 1 to be a JVM except in a container or jail. `jps` lists the running JVMs you can attach to, with options to include JVM arguments and/or application arguments.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. You should put that into an answer :) Does this imply that the same verification cannot be achieved with `java`? Unlike `jinfo` it cannot be attached to a running JVM?
(And yes, I'm passing arguments to a Java process `1` inside a Docker container)

Comment: This is getting long enough I'd better :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's (at least) two different JVMs.**

[Expanding comment:] `java {nothing} -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` creates a new JVM, changes none of its configuration from the default, and prints the resulting configuration, which is the default configuration with no changes -- and the default for MaxDirectMemSize is indeed zero.

OTOH `jinfo {option} pid` attaches to an *existing already running* JVM and obtains or changes the configuration of that JVM (although the specific pid 1 isn't usually a JVM but it often is in a docker container as you are using). `jps` lists the running JVMs you can attach to, with options to include JVM arguments and/or application arguments.

> Does this imply that the same verification cannot be achieved with `java`? Unlike `jinfo` it cannot be attached to a running JVM?

Yes and no; it gets a bit Wonderlandy.

`java` *by itself* creates a new JVM, separate from any existing one. Normally this JVM runs a user-specified program, but with `-version` as you used it just prints version info and exits without running anything.

Now, the [attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/package-summary.html) is accessible from (and actually written partly in) Java. What `jinfo` does in more detail is:

1. create a new JVM; this doesn't use the `java` executable, so it isn't easily visible, but it actually is a JVM just like one from `java`
2. use that JVM to run some predefined Java code, which used to be in JDK/lib/tools.jar; I haven't bothered to track down where it is (and exactly how to access it) in the new post-8 modulated Java
3. that Java code when run in the `jinfo` JVM attaches to, and accesses information in, the specified *other* JVM, which was previously created and configured with `java -Xvarious` to run your application

You can actually do steps 2 and 3 yourself; you could write Java code that uses the API to attach to a specified (or otherwise located) existing JVM and get the info you want, and use `java` to run in JVM#2 your code that accesses info in existing JVM#1. But why bother, when `jinfo` (and `jstat jmap jconsole` etc) already does what is needed?

For that matter, `jps` also does this -- it runs its own JVM to run Java 'tool' code that uses the attach API to list JVMs. That's why the list produced by `jps`, unless filtered, includes `jps` itself. In fact, if you could run `jps` during the very short time `jinfo` is running, the `jps` list would include `jinfo` also -- and if you could determine the pid for `jps` and run `jinfo` on that pid during the very short time `jps` is running, you could get `jinfo`-type information on the `jps` JVM.

Clear enough?